# How to customize Emails from shop-api-plugin

Tags: php, api, symfony, sylius

I'm triying to override the emails templates from shop-api-plugin  in a Symfony/Sylius app.

I've been able to customize the emails from the shopBundle, but not from the api.

Need help please :)

If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: Please add related code, so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

just overwrite email template twig and override the configuration with the new twig path

```
 sylius_mailer:
    emails:
        api_verification_token:
            subject: sylius.emails.user.verification_token.subject
            template: "SyliusShopApiPlugin:Email:verification.html.twig"
        api_reset_password_token:
            subject: sylius.emails.user.reset_password_token.subject
            template: "SyliusShopApiPlugin:Email:passwordReset.html.twig"
        api_order_confirmation:
            subject: sylius.emails.order_confirmation.subject
            template: "SyliusShopApiPlugin:Email:orderConfirmation.html.twig"
```